# Find and get id of 2 clicked buttons in sequence

Tags: java, android

I am making a program of clicking the same 2 dublicate pics.
If user clicked the wrong pic after clicking the 1st pic, there will be negative value. If the two pics are same, I set those buttons to clickable(false). But my problem is, when the second pic is not same as 1st pic, I want to set clickable(true) to second pic, as well as the 1st pic but I have no idea how to get the id of 1st clicked button.

I have 16buttons and in this, I posted button1, other buttons are similar.
my code is.....

```
 Collections.shuffle(buttonResources);
        for(int i = 0; i < buttonResources.size(); i++)
        {
            ImageButton bt = findViewById(buttonResources.get(i));
            buttons.add(bt);
            bt.setBackgroundResource(pics.get(i/2));
            bt.setTag(pics.get(i/2));
            aaa = pics.get(i/2);
            bt.setOnClickListener(this);
            bt.setClickable(false);
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation0 = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
                alphaAnimation0.setDuration(200);
                alphaAnimation0.setFillAfter(true);

                for(int i = 0; i < buttonResources.size(); i++)
                {
                    ImageButton bt = findViewById(buttonResources.get(i));
                    buttons.add(bt);
                    bt.startAnimation(alphaAnimation0);

                    bt.setClickable(true);
                }

            }
        }, 5000);




        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v1) {
        switch (v1.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt1:
                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                alphaAnimation1.setDuration(300);
                alphaAnimation1.setFillAfter(true);
                bt1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation1);
                aaa = (int) bt1.getTag();
                bt1.setClickable(false);

                if(bbb==0){
                    bt1.setClickable(false);
                    bbb = aaa;
                }else if (bbb==aaa){
                    right++;
                    tvtext.setText("Right" + right + "wRONG" + wrong);
                    bbb=0;

                }else{
                    wrong++;
                    tvtext.setText("Right" + right + "wRONG" + wrong);
                    bbb=0;
                    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
                    alphaAnimation.setDuration(600);
                    alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                    bt1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
                    bt1.setClickable(true);
                    }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `int bbbID=0;`
then add these changes:

```
case R.id.bt1:
                AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                alphaAnimation1.setDuration(300);
                alphaAnimation1.setFillAfter(true);
                bt1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation1);
                aaa = (int) bt1.getTag();
                bt1.setClickable(false);

                if(bbb==0){
                    bt1.setClickable(false);
                    bbb = aaa;
                    bbbID = v1.getId();   //////change
                }else if (bbb==aaa){
                    right++;
                    tvtext.setText("Right" + right + "wRONG" + wrong);
                    bbb=0;
                    bbbID = 0;   //////change

                }else{
                    wrong++;
                    tvtext.setText("Right" + right + "wRONG" + wrong);
                    bbb=0;
                    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
                    alphaAnimation.setDuration(600);
                    alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
                    bt1.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
                    bt1.setClickable(true);
                    for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++){   //////change
                       if(buttons.get(i).getId() == bbbID){   //////change
                           buttons.get(i).setClickable(true);   //////change
                       }
                    }
                    }
                break;
```

Comment: @JohnSmith happy to hear that :)